# modify a HTTP POST request body (post parameter) when the particular POST request is triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to be able to intercept a HTTP Post Request when it is triggered and then modify its request body (or parameter ) and then send it.

How is this possible with jquery/js.

Thanks

Comment: How is it currently triggered?

Comment: Its triggered when a user clicks on another url(then this post request is made behind the scene)

Answer (score 1):

Jquery ajax `beforeSend` event should do the trick.

According to the [JQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/):

> **beforeSend** (Local Event)
>   This event, which is triggered before an Ajax request is started, allows you to modify the XMLHttpRequest
>   object